# In windows phone, FindFirstFileEx() returns INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE and GetLastError() gives Access is denied

Tags: c++, winapi, visual-c++, windows-phone-8, windows-phone

I used [FindFirstFileEx()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/aa364419(v=vs.105).aspx) just to traverse through the files and folders of any folder in Windows Phone, say SD card\Pictures. But the function have returned INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE  then I used GetLastError() and I got error code '5' (i.e. Access is denied).

```
if (FindFirstFileEx(szPath->Data(), FindExInfoBasic, &FindFileData, FindExSearchLimitToDirectories, NULL, 0) == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE)
    return GetLastError();
```

here I got return value '5' and my code snippet is here,

```
int TraverseFolder()
{
    WIN32_FIND_DATA FindFileData;
    HANDLE hFindData;
    int nCount = 0;

    hFindData = FindFirstFileEx("D:\\Pictures\\", FindExInfoStandard, &FindFileData, FindExSearchLimitToDirectories, NULL, 0);

    if (hFindData == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE)
        return -1;                         //here I got GetLastError() value as 5

    do
    {
        String^ szDataName = ref new String(FindFileData.cFileName);

        if (szDataName != "." && DataName != "..")
        {
            .....
            .....
            nCount++;
        }

    } while (FindNextFile(hFindData, &FindFileData));

    FindClose(hFindData);

    return nCount;
}
```

My question is, how to traverse through folders in windows phone and why it says 'Access is denied'?

Comment: And where is the question?

Comment: @JochenKalmbach how to traverse through folders in windows phone?

Comment: Since you linked to documentation and all, perhaps this line may warrant another look : "To examine a directory that is not a root directory, use the path to that directory, **without a trailing backslash.**" (emphasis added). Not saying it is your problem, but you may as well play by their rules before telling the referee he's blind as a bat. It may well be you simply don't have permission, but call it per-the-docs first. I'm pretty sure that should be `drive:\\Path\\To\\Folder\\*`

Comment: Access denied means just that. You don't have sufficient rights.

Comment: You cannot traverse the file system on Windows Phone. It is protected by the system to ensure system integrity. You may also want to point out, that you're not actually writing C++, but rather C++/CLI.